# How do I pipe each command given to the shell?

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

I'd like to edit my .bashrc so that every command executed on the shell is piped to something, for example:

```
 $ sudo apt update
  _________________
< sudo apt update >
 -----------------
    \   ^__^
     \  (oo)\_______
        (__)\       )\/\
            ||----w |
            ||     ||
```

I have managed something rather similar, but not entirely:

```
$ bash
$ exec > >(cowsay)
$ echo "Hello AU!"
$ exit
 _______
< Hello AU! >
 -------
    \   ^__^
     \  (oo)\_______
        (__)\       )\/\
            ||----w |
            ||     ||
```

It is not the desired result, as it only happens after exiting the current shell.

It's mainly for fun/learning purposes.

Comment: Using the `-n` flag to `cowsay` is useful; it makes it preserve whitespace.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can adapt your method a bit. Instead of piping to `cowsay` directly, read output till a delimiting character, send that output to `cowsay`, then print that character after every command:

```
exec > >(while IFS= read -d '' -r line; do if [[ -n $line ]]; then echo; printf "%s\n" "$line" | cowsay; fi; done)
PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\0"'
```

Here, I'm using the ASCII NUL character. You can use something else that's unlikely to appear in command output.

This will print after the prompt, so the output will be ugly:

```
$ export LC_ALL=C
$ exec > >(while IFS= read -d '' -r line; do if [[ -n $line ]]; then echo; printf "%s\n" "$line" | cowsay; fi; done)
$ PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\0"'
$ ls
$
 ______________________________________
/ Desktop Documents Downloads Music    \
| Pictures Public Templates Videos
\ examples.desktop                     /
 --------------------------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||

$ echo foo
$
 ______
< foo  >
 ------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

Note that this will break any command which tries complex output or has a text user interface (think command line editors, pagers, etc.).

Assuming you already know what `exec > >(...)` does, the part in the process substitution is:

- `while IFS= read -d '' -r line; do ... done`: this is a fairly common idiom for reading  data delimited by the ASCII NUL character:

  - `IFS=` sets the IFS to the empty string, which disables field splitting
  - `-r` prevents `read` from treating `\` in the input specially (so, `\n` for example, is read as `\n` and not converted to the newline character).
  - `-d ''` is the way to tell `read` to read until the NUL character

  So the whole thing loops over input in NUL-delimited sections, while preserving the contents of the input as much as possible.
- `if [[ -n $line ]]; then ... fi; done` - only act if the input read so far is not empty.
- `echo; printf "%s\n" "$line" | cowsay;` - print a leading empty line, so that the cowsay output doesn't clash with the prompt, and then send the input read so far to cowsay. `printf` is more reliable and safer than `echo`.

Comment: As my prompt has a linebreak in it the cowsay output *does* clash with the second part of it – maybe also set the prompt to something non-distracting?

Answer (score 16):

You can `trap` and abuse bash's `DEBUG` signal:

```
trap 'bash -c "$BASH_COMMAND" | cowsay' DEBUG
```

#### Example run

```
$ trap 'bash -c "$BASH_COMMAND" | cowsay' DEBUG
$ echo "AU is awesome!"
 __________________
< AU is awesome! >
 ------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
AU is awesome!
```

However, this will still execute the command afterwards. Thanks to [ilkkachu](https://askubuntu.com/users/551198/ilkkachu) I found a way around that:

```
$ shopt -s extdebug
$ trap 'bash -c "$BASH_COMMAND" | cowsay; false' DEBUG
$ echo "AU is awesome!"
 __________________
< AU is awesome! >
 ------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```